# How to execute the most recent file in a folder (just downloaded) with a Powershell script

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run the most recently downloaded **.exe** in a directory. The script that I am testing is as follows:

```
$dir = "C:/Users/$env:UserName/Downloads"

$latest = Get-ChildItem -path $dir | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1

$go = Start-Process :C/Users/$env:UserName/Downloads/$latest.name | Out-Null

Invoke-Expression $go
```

I am unsure of how to actually pass the newly downloaded file as a variable for Powershell to recognize. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to run the exe file, I think you could just do this:

```
$file = Get-ChildItem -path Path | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1


& $file.FullName
```

The `&` is a call operator for when you want to execute a command,script or function. The `$file.FullName` will give you the full path to the `exe`.

Comment: Thank you, that resolved my problem. I appreciate the insight.